# NRF24L01+ scanning and connecting to wifi hotspots or creating one

Tags: arduino-mega, wifi, nrf24l01+

I've seen this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=issW8aeM5tY) so I think I can connect it through my wifi router to any device. How can I scan for and discover wifi hotspots and then connect to it? Or is there a way to create wifi hotspot of it's own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does seem possible, check out [this thread](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=54795.0) on Arduino forums, where cpixip worked directly with the NRF24 SPI interface to accomplish that.

Here is the code he published, in case the link won't be available:

```
#include <SPI.h>

// Poor Man's Wireless 2.4GHz Scanner
//
// uses an nRF24L01p connected to an Arduino
// 
// Cables are:
//     SS       -> 10
//     MOSI     -> 11
//     MISO     -> 12
//     SCK      -> 13
// 
// and CE       ->  9
//
// created March 2011 by Rolf Henkel
//

#define CE  9

// Array to hold Channel data
#define CHANNELS  64
int channel[CHANNELS];

// greyscale mapping 
int  line;
char grey[] = " .:-=+*aRW";

// nRF24L01P registers we need
#define _NRF24_CONFIG      0x00
#define _NRF24_EN_AA       0x01
#define _NRF24_RF_CH       0x05
#define _NRF24_RF_SETUP    0x06
#define _NRF24_RPD         0x09

// get the value of a nRF24L01p register
byte getRegister(byte r)
{
 byte c;

 PORTB &=~_BV(2);
 c = SPI.transfer(r&0x1F);
 c = SPI.transfer(0);  
 PORTB |= _BV(2);

 return(c);
}

// set the value of a nRF24L01p register
void setRegister(byte r, byte v)
{
 PORTB &=~_BV(2);
 SPI.transfer((r&0x1F)|0x20);
 SPI.transfer(v);
 PORTB |= _BV(2);
}

// power up the nRF24L01p chip
void powerUp(void)
{
 setRegister(_NRF24_CONFIG,getRegister(_NRF24_CONFIG)|0x02);
 delayMicroseconds(130);
}

// switch nRF24L01p off
void powerDown(void)
{
 setRegister(_NRF24_CONFIG,getRegister(_NRF24_CONFIG)&~0x02);
}

// enable RX 
void enable(void)
{
   PORTB |= _BV(1);
}

// disable RX
void disable(void)
{
   PORTB &=~_BV(1);
}

// setup RX-Mode of nRF24L01p
void setRX(void)
{
 setRegister(_NRF24_CONFIG,getRegister(_NRF24_CONFIG)|0x01);
 enable();
 // this is slightly shorter than
 // the recommended delay of 130 usec
 // - but it works for me and speeds things up a little...
 delayMicroseconds(100);
}

// scanning all channels in the 2.4GHz band
void scanChannels(void)
{
 disable();
 for( int j=0 ; j<200  ; j++)
 {
   for( int i=0 ; i<CHANNELS ; i++)
   {
     // select a new channel
     setRegister(_NRF24_RF_CH,(128*i)/CHANNELS);

     // switch on RX
     setRX();

     // wait enough for RX-things to settle
     delayMicroseconds(40);

     // this is actually the point where the RPD-flag
     // is set, when CE goes low
     disable();

     // read out RPD flag; set to 1 if 
     // received power > -64dBm
     if( getRegister(_NRF24_RPD)>0 )   channel[i]++;
   }
 }
}

// outputs channel data as a simple grey map
void outputChannels(void)
{
 int norm = 0;

 // find the maximal count in channel array
 for( int i=0 ; i<CHANNELS ; i++)
   if( channel[i]>norm ) norm = channel[i];

 // now output the data
 Serial.print('|');
 for( int i=0 ; i<CHANNELS ; i++)
 {
   int pos;

   // calculate grey value position
   if( norm!=0 ) pos = (channel[i]*10)/norm;
   else          pos = 0;

   // boost low values
   if( pos==0 && channel[i]>0 ) pos++;

   // clamp large values
   if( pos>9 ) pos = 9;

   // print it out
   Serial.print(grey[pos]);
   channel[i] = 0;
 }

 // indicate overall power
 Serial.print("| ");
 Serial.println(norm);
}

// give a visual reference between WLAN-channels and displayed data
void printChannels(void)
{
 // output approximate positions of WLAN-channels
 Serial.println(">      1 2  3 4  5  6 7 8  9 10 11 12 13  14                     <");
}

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(57600);

 Serial.println("Starting Poor Man's Wireless 2.4GHz Scanner ...");
 Serial.println();

 // Channel Layout
 // 0         1         2         3         4         5         6
 // 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123
 //       1 2  3 4  5  6 7 8  9 10 11 12 13  14                     | 
 //
 Serial.println("Channel Layout");
 printChannels();

 // Setup SPI
 SPI.begin();
 SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);
 SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV2);
 SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);

 // Activate Chip Enable
 pinMode(CE,OUTPUT);
 disable();

 // now start receiver
 powerUp();

 // switch off Shockburst
 setRegister(_NRF24_EN_AA,0x0);

 // make sure RF-section is set properly 
 // - just write default value... 
 setRegister(_NRF24_RF_SETUP,0x0F); 

 // reset line counter
 line = 0;
}

void loop() 
{ 
 // do the scan
 scanChannels();

 // output the result
 outputChannels();

 // output WLAN-channel reference every 12th line
 if( line++>12 )
 {
   printChannels();
   line = 0;
 }
}
```

The pinout seems to match the NRF24 library pinout.
Please note that it seems this project does not implement the WiFi stack, but only check a high enough signal ( > -64dBm) for a given channel.

In order to create a WiFi hotspot, implementing the 802.11 stack is inevitable, and it seems like the Arduino core chip (atmega328) is not suitable for implementing it using software and bit-banging, so a dedicated hardware will be necessary.

Comment: I'm using Arduino Mega which has ATmega2560 chip. Do you think wifi stack can be implemented on this? Can you also provide me some tutorial or other helpful links about wifi stack please? I am new to wifi stack thing.

Comment: You can read more about 802.11 in wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11 . It seems that a microcontroller running around 16MHz won't do the job. Also, implementing the network stack by yourself is not recommend for beginners. Nevertheless, there is also a nice gateway solution, check out this thread: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=187274.0

Comment: if I use this [ESP8266](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-shipping-ESP8266-serial-WIFI-wireless-module-wireless-transceiver/2031529724.html) module, do you think I can work without implementing any wifi stack?

Comment: Looks like this module should work, check out this instructable: http://www.instructables.com/id/ESP8266-Wifi-Temperature-Logger/

Comment: Anybody, please check this question of mine. ([link](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/4963/sim908c-gsm-module-with-arduino-mega-without-any-shield)) I edited this question now, since no one is answering it, I thought I would post it here.

Answer (score 2):

I believe nRF2401 is low level tx/rx chip working in 2.4GHz band. But it's not WiFi module. To use it as WiFi you probably need implement WiFi stack. I think guy in video set up channel and counting receved data only.

Comment: It's all right if i can only send and receive data, all i need is i can search, discover and connect with the nrf module using any wifi enabled device.

Comment: The issue is more fundamental than implementing a wifi stack - the nRF24L01 radio does not have the bandwidth and modulation types needed to support wifi.